# Restore transactions in app purchase android using soomla in Cocos2dx

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, soomla

Getting following error on this line

soomla::CCStoreController::`sharedStoreController()->restoreTransactions();`

```
    06-20 12:34:55.858: E/SOOMLA PurchaseObserver(28017): Illegal state for operation (restorePurchases): IAB helper is not set up.
    06-20 12:34:55.868: E/SoomlaNDKGlue(28017): java.lang.IllegalStateException: IAB helper is not set up. Can't perform operation: restorePurchases
    06-20 12:34:55.868: E/SoomlaNDKGlue(28017):     at com.soomla.store.billing.IabHelper.checkSetupDoneAndThrow(IabHelper.java:433)
    06-20 12:34:55.868: E/SoomlaNDKGlue(28017):     at com.soomla.store.billing.IabHelper.restorePurchasesAsync(IabHelper.java:112)
    06-20 12:34:55.868: E/SoomlaNDKGlue(28017):     at com.soomla.store.billing.google.GooglePlayIabService.restorePurchasesAsync(GooglePlayIabService.java:66)
    06-20 12:34:55.868: E/SoomlaNDKGlue(28017):     at com.soomla.store.StoreController$3.success(StoreController.java:233)
    06-20 12:34:55.868: E/SoomlaNDKGlue(28017):     at com.soomla.store.billing.google.GooglePlayIabService.startIabHelper(GooglePlayIabService.java:164)
    06-20 12:34:55.868: E/SoomlaNDKGlue(28017):     at com.soomla.store.billing.google.GooglePlayIabService.initializeBillingService(GooglePlayIabService.java:47)
    06-20 12:34:55.868: E/SoomlaNDKGlue(28017):     at com.soomla.store.StoreController.restoreTransactions(StoreController.java:193)
    06-20 12:34:55.868: E/SoomlaNDKGlue(28017):     at com.soomla.store.StoreController.restoreTransactions(StoreController.java:183)
    06-20 12:34:55.868: E/SoomlaNDKGlue(28017):     at com.soomla.cocos2dx.store.StoreControllerBridge.restoreTransactions(StoreControllerBridge.java:67)
    06-20 12:34:55.868: E/SoomlaNDKGlue(28017):     at com.soomla.cocos2dx.store.SoomlaNDKGlue.dispatchNDKCall(SoomlaNDKGlue.java:74)
    06-20 12:34:55.868: E/SoomlaNDKGlue(28017):     at com.soomla.cocos2dx.store.SoomlaNDKGlue.receiveCppMessage(SoomlaNDKGlue.java:31)
    06-20 12:34:55.868: E/SoomlaNDKGlue(28017):     at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.nativeInit(Native Method)
    06-20 12:34:55.868: E/SoomlaNDKGlue(28017):     at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(Cocos2dxRenderer.java:72)
    06-20 12:34:55.868: E/SoomlaNDKGlue(28017):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1494)
    06-20 12:34:55.868: E/SoomlaNDKGlue(28017):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
    06-20 12:34:55.868: E/SoomlaNDKGlue(28017): Unknown exception (java.lang.IllegalStateException: IAB helper is not set up. Can't perform operation: restorePurchases)
    06-20 12:34:55.868: D/cocos2d-x debug info(28017): CCSoomlaError SOOMLA/Cocos2DX Got Unknown exception
```

this is first in app purchase i am doing.....Cocos2dx   in   c++
How to restore transactions of in app purchases if app is reinstalled, having same  account id from which pruchasing was done
OR is there any other way to restore transactions using soomla.

Comment: I would recommend also posting this question at http://answers.soom.la

Comment: Do you use Android emulator for the testing? If so, I guess you should install additional software for Google Play.

Comment: I am using device only not an emulator.

Comment: where to add this line of code--in event handler or other place.

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of issues were fixed in newer versions of SOOMLA.